# How do I get this filter to return a value from $http or $resource

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my html i have something like {{ i.userId | userName }} . Basically I am trying to convert it to a name. I am using a filter to do it but I having many problems with the async function to get the data.

```
                app.filter('userName', function($http) {
                     return function(value) {
                         if (!value) return '';

                         var user;
                         $http({
                             method: 'GET',
                             url: 'http://localhost:3000/api/Users?filter=                                                                                                      
                             {"where":{"id":' + value + '}}'
                         }).success(function(response) {
                             user = response;
                         });

                         return user.name;

                     }
                 });
```

I tried to put it in a callback format but I couldn't get it to work.

Comment: filter with an ajax...that will make a mess..Do you know it will get called on each digest..

Answer (score 0):

Using async call in filter will not work as Angular assumes your filters are side effect free and only executes them when the model changes. Before the async call returns the filter has done its work and will not get called in future till model updates.

Your options are to make the filter stateful by defining `$stateful` property on the filter function:

```
function filterFunction(value) {
    if (!value) return '';

    var user;
    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'http://localhost:3000/api/Users?filter=                                                                                                      
                                 {"where":{"id":' + value + '}}'
    }).success(function (response) {
        user = response;
    });

    return user.name;

}
filterFunction.$stateful = true;
return filterFunction;
```

When you make the filter stateful as above, Angular will evaluate this on each digest cycle. So this is not performant at all.

Please see the [developer guide](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter) on filter

Better way will be to get the user list at one go and then search in this list by implementing a custom filter that takes this list as input too.